# How to access the text of a particular row of an outline control with AppleScript?

Tags: applescript, nsoutlineview

I'm trying to select a particular row of an outline using AppleScript, based on its text.

Here's what I'm considering (but doesn't work):

```
repeat with aRow in rows of outline 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of window 1
    set t to text of cell of aRow
    if t starts with "some text" then select aRow
end repeat
```

The problem is that `text of cell of aRow` doesn't resolve to what I think it should.
I've used the Accessibility Inspector to confirm the object hierarchy. I've tried using "UI Elements" on the row to see what elements are accessible, but it doesn't return anything useful. So I'm out of idea! What am I missing?

Comment: Er... for what Application...

Comment: One I'm developing. I'm using AppleScript for automated UI testing. I'm new to AppleScript, why would that be relevant?

Comment: Because it helps if we can try and access the outline ourselves. Not all applications give you access to the info as you would expect. As your the developer afaik you should be able to name the objects and put in any relevant info yourself. But I have not tried this my self.

Comment: By the way if you are developing it. It may be best for you to make it scriptable rather than having users buggering about with the GUI. have a look at https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptableCocoaApplications/SApps_intro/SAppsIntro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001982-BCICHGIE  and https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2002/tn2106.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With @markhunte's hint, I worked out how to reach the text of a row in the outline, using `UI Elements` and `get properties`. It turns out the `AXRow > AXCell > AXStaticText`hierarchy displayed by the Accessibility Inspector was misleading.

The text of each is access through `name of first UI Element of row (of outline...)`.

Here's the working code that does what I intended to achieve:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "MyApp"

        repeat with aRow in row of outline 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of window 1
            if name of first UI element of aRow starts with "Schedule" then select aRow
        end repeat

    end tel
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the thing you are missing is **static text**.

Here is an example of it with iTunes.

```
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "iTunes"

            --  get properties of every static text in rows of outline 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of window 1

            get properties of first static text in rows of outline 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of window 1 whose description is "sources"
            get properties of first static text in rows of outline 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of window 1 whose name is "LIBRARY"
            get properties of first static text in rows of outline 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of window 1 whose value is "Spanish"


        end tell
    end tell
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, you set me on the right track by showing me the get properties stuff. The actual answer is slightly different because I was misled by the Accessibility Inspector. More details in my answer. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad it helped. Been a long time since I have played with GUI scripting forgot most of it. Not my fav.